# "Unable to locate package"

Tags: updates

When I run `sudo apt install bc` (as well as other packages) I get:

```
$ sudo apt install bc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package bc
```

This is a new clean install of 16.04, xenial server

Comment: Did you do `sudo apt update` yet at all?

Comment: Yes.  It takes over 10 minutes to finish and does not update the system

Comment: it's not *supposed* to update the system, it's supposed to get information about packages that're available for installation and refreshes the repository cache information.

Comment: First run `sudo apt update`then run `sudo apt install bc`

Comment: After 10 minutes I get this: y:/$ sudo apt update
[sudo] password for 
Ign:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Ign:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
Ign:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
Err:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
Err:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
Err:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]

Comment: After running sudo apt update followed by sudo apt install bc I get the same result:  "Unable to locate package bc"

Comment: Is your internet connection working at all? Or maybe there is a temporary error with your internet connection?

Comment: Internet connect is fine

Comment: According to the output there is a problem to get information from the Ubuntu archives. Maybe the connection will work after half an hour -- try again ...

Comment: This has been an ongoing problem.  The internet connection is fine

Comment: The problem might be at the other end, the Ubuntu archive end, of the connection. I live in Europe and use other Ubuntu archives (and they work now).